# 'Entity Reference to taxonomy' Field in chosen format is not allowing to add new terms?

Tags: 8, entities, taxonomy-terms

I Installed [Chosen module](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) and I have created field referencing to a taxonomy in one of my content type. But this is not taking the newly entered term, though i checked 'create new term if not exist' in manage field settings as shown in below image:
[image]

Or Any idea How to remove tid from autocomplete selection.Same question is already asked before like in [link1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227954/how-to-remove-taxonomy-id-number-which-comes-along-with-term-name-from-node-add) ,[link2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146983/how-can-i-hide-the-entity-id-on-autocomplete-widget), but i didnt get proper solution.

Comment: What do you mean by " But this is not taking the newly entered term"? 
You have an error message when submitting the form, or you add it and after saving it disappears? Or how?

Comment: Term ,which is not added to that particular vocabulary.