# How to show filtered content as suggestion of "reference autocomplete field" based on a field value of reference content

Tags: ajax

Say, one content type is "CONCEPT" and it has a field named 'STATUS'. 
Another content type is "Article" and it has a node-reference auto-complete field named 'CONCEPT FROM'.

Now I want to see only "CONCEPT" contents whose status value is "ACCEPTED" as a suggestion of "CONCEPT FROM" auto-complete field.

Comment: You have to create a view & apply filter on them that "Show CONCEPT whose STATUS is ACCEPTED"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the [entity reference module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference), what you can do is autocomplete from an entity reference view. You can add a filter on your entity reference view that filters nodes of type CONCEPT with a status field value of ACCEPTED. Once your view is created, you can select it under the **Entity selection** fieldset.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @shawn-conn
His answer is perfect but I can't give vote because of minimum reputation. See following solution in details:

**Step 1:**
First create one [entity reference view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42034/how-to-create-a-view-type-of-entity-reference-display)
*Note: In this view include referenced content type (e.g.: CONCEPT) and it's filter/condition field (e.g.: STATUS)*

**Step 2:**
From **MANAGE FIELDS** of the required content type (e.g.: PROJECT), Add field that **FIELD TYPE** will be [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) and WIDGET will be **autocomplete** then click on the **SAVE** button.

Step 3:
Now choose **Views: Filter by an entity reference view** option in **MODE** field and choose your **views** that is created in **Step 1** in **View used to select the entities** field from ENTITY SELECTION section of the field settings page.
[image]

Step 4:
Click on the **Save settings** button to save changes.