# Content editor cannot view unpublished taxonomy terms when editing a node

Tags: taxonomy-terms

We have a custom content type that has a Entity Reference field to a taxonomy vocabulary. The content editor is presented a list of check boxes to select their terms to attach to the node. Some of our terms are published and some aren't. When I am logged in as admin (user 1), I can see ALL of the terms to select from, but when a content editor is logged in, they are only seeing the published terms to select from. We want the editor to still be able to tag content with unpublished terms. I have tried every permission I can think of without just opening it up fully to a content editor. We have content moderation in place so the editors have semi locked down permissions in order to allow a content manager to review and publish the content.

Does anyone know the specific permission that would allow editors to see unpublished taxonomy terms on the node edit page?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use permissions, just adjust the field's reference method.

[Add a new entity reference display view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42034/how-to-create-a-view-type-of-entity-reference-display) that returns all taxonomy of the given type with the published = 1 filter removed (so it display all terms regardless of publish status).

Edit your entity reference taxonomy field for the relevant node type. Under the **Reference Type**, adjust **Reference method** to *Views: Filter by an entity reference view*, then select your newly created view.

After saving the field settings, the node form should display all taxonomy regardless of user permissions on viewing unpublished content.